# Response.TransmitFile sending zero byte file

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httphandler

I am trying to download a zip file through custom handler. The file is downloaded as zero byte zip file. But the original file is not a zero byte zip file.

The code in the `ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` is

```
String file = Directory.GetFiles(cachePath).FirstOrDefault();
String filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
context.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
//byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
//context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
context.Response.TransmitFile(file);
context.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need `Content-Length`

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", new FileInfo(file).Length.ToString());
```

Or perhaps you are missing `ContentType`

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

As a last resort it may be caching related.

```
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have not posted the complete code and the actual issue is in some other part of code.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks accurate. I am using a pretty much identical snippet to perform file downloading on my website. The only thing that I can't see is the path that you are retrieving the file from. You may need to do a HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath to get the actual path to the file.

Comment: Thanks. I have problem is some other part of the code which i have not posted